# Synchronize HorizontalScrollView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with vertical orientation, each item of list consist of HorizontalScrollView in brief it's some kind of table with scrollable rows(check pic below)
 [image]

When I scroll one of the horizontal view all others views should be also scrolled
What I already done:

```
private int scrollDistance;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.binding.scrollView.post(() -> holder.binding.scrollView.scrollTo(scrollDistance, 0));
    holder.binding.scrollView.setChangeListener(dx -> {
        for (int i = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); i <= layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition(); i++) {
        View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(i);
        if (view == null) {
            continue;
        }
        HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        if (scrollView != null) {
            scrollView.scrollTo(dx, 0);
        }
    }
    scrollDistance = dx;
    });
}
```

It works but when I start scroll down or up sometimes happen that HorizontalScrollView keeps old position.

**Question:** How I can synchronize all views at the same position?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: HorizontalScrollView items will get recreate because vertical items will also get recreated when you scroll vertical and positions are not gonna be maintained this is default functionality of recyclerview or listview in android.

Comment: YLS, I know it, for this I remember scroll position and when each item recreated I set to right position